# Solve P(x) ≡ x^3 - x^2 + x -1 ≡ 0 mod(2^i), for i=1,2,3,4.

Tags: number-theory

Here is what I got so far:

For i=1:

x ≡ 1 mod (2) is a solution to P(x)≡0 mod (2).
P'(x) ≡ 3x^2 -2x + 1

So, P'(x) ≡ P'(1) = 3-2+1 ≡ 1+1 ≡ 2 mod (2) and P(1) ≡ mod (2).
Then, by Hensel's Lifting, p^(i+1) = p^2 | 0.

So, P(x) ≡ mod(2^2) has 2(=p) two distinct solutions of the form x ≡ 1 + 2t mod(2^2), where t = 1,2,.....,p-1.

I don't know how to go from here to find solutions for i=3,4 for mod(2^i). Can anybody show me an easier way because I'm getting terribly confused with this procedure? Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you *supposed* to use heavy-duty machinery for such small numbers?

Comment: Is there an easier method that I can employ for the solution?

Comment: Check all values :-)

Answer (score 4):

Note that we are looking at $(x-1)(x^2+1)$.

There are no even solutions. If $x$ is odd, then $x^2+1\equiv 2\pmod{4}$. Thus we need $x-1$ to be divisible by $2^{n-1}$. For any $n\gt 1$, the solutions modulo $2^n$ are $1$ and $1+2^{n-1}$.

**Remark:** Lifting will also work. But the polynomial is so nakedly factorable that I doubt this was intended to be an exercise in lifting.

We gave a **general** solution. However, the problem only asks about $i=1,2,3,4$. So we are solving the congruence modulo $4$ different small numbers. For $2^4$, "try everything," that is, try the numbers $0$ to $15$. It will be soon clear that the even numbers are hopeless. Once we have the answers modulo $16$, we can read off the answers modulo the smaller powers.

Or else go the more natural way, from $i=1$ to $i=4$. There is very little work to do!

Comment: When I used lifting, I got a solution of x ≡ 1 for all four moduli. Is this correct?

Comment: $x\equiv 1$ is the only solution modulo $2$. Modulo $4$, $8$, and $16$, there are in each case two solutions, the $1$ that you mentioned in the comment, and respectively $3$, $5$, and $9$.